# Arrow keys overridden by parent and don't work in input child

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a parent big table that overrides the arrow keys to navigate through cells. On click on a cell a search opens and because that search is inside the table, the arrow keys cannot be used to move the pointer through the text written into the actual input element as they now just navigate between the table cells

Any idea how I can stop this functionality to be overridden only for the searchbox child, basically to stop its propagation? The table is in an external library so there's no access to it.

Comment: Please include relevant code so that the community members can understand the problem and give better answers

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was easier than expected.

Just had to attach an event listener for `keydown` event on that input and stop the propagation of the event.